# AsyncTask keeps repeating onResume

Tags: android, listview, concurrency, android-asynctask, onresume

I'm making an Android application that gets data from Google Places and displays the data on a listview. The problem is that the asynctask keeps refreshing and making http requests which eventually leads to outOfBounds on my adapter. I'm using a service to get the location of the device and send it to the activity that gets the locations through a broadcast receiver.

Is the issue that onResume keeps getting called?

Is the onRecieve method of the broadcast receiver constantly called?

Is the locationListener on the Service repeating?

Thanks in advance!

The Activity with listView, broadcastReceiver and AsyncTask:

```
public class NearbyLocationsActivity extends BaseActivity implements AsyncDelegate {
private Location mLastLocation;
private GetLocations nearbyLocations;
private PlaceAdapter adapter;

private ArrayList<Place> nearbyPlaces;

private double mLat;
private double mLong;

private ListView locationsList;

public Spinner typesSpinner;

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

private String radius = "10000";

private int selectedSpinnerIndex;

private String [] types = {"everything", "restaurant", "bar", "museum", "night_club", "cafe", "movie_theater"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_locations);

    locationsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.locations_list);
    typesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.type_spinner);

    nearbyPlaces = new ArrayList();

    adapter = new PlaceAdapter(getApplicationContext(), nearbyPlaces);
    locationsList.setAdapter(adapter);

    if(!runtimePermissions()) {
        enableService();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    return true;
}

public void enableService() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
    startService(i);
}

private boolean runtimePermissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 100);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (broadcastReceiver == null) {
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                mLastLocation = (Location) intent.getExtras().get("coordinates");
                mLat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                mLong = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                nearbyLocations = new GetLocations(NearbyLocationsActivity.this);
                nearbyLocations.execute();
            }
        };
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_updates"));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (broadcastReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
    stopService(i);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            enableService();
        } else {
            runtimePermissions();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void asyncComplete(boolean success) {
    typesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedSpinnerIndex = typesSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            new GetLocations(NearbyLocationsActivity.this).execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            selectedSpinnerIndex = 0;
        }
    });

    locationsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Place p = adapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateEventActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selectedPlace", p);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public class GetLocations extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private AsyncDelegate delegate;

    public GetLocations (AsyncDelegate delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        nearbyPlaces.clear();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String http = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + mLat + "," + mLong +
                "&radius=10000";

        if (selectedSpinnerIndex != 0) {
            http += "&types=" + types[selectedSpinnerIndex];
        }

        http += "&key=AIzaSyDFb37i6VGPj2EG6L7dLO5H7tDhLCqCW2k";

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(http);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject placeLine = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                Place place = new Place();
                JSONObject geometryLine = placeLine.getJSONObject("geometry");
                JSONObject locationLine = geometryLine.getJSONObject("location");
                Place.Location location = new Place.Location();
                location.setLat(locationLine.getDouble("lat"));
                location.setLon(locationLine.getDouble("lng"));
                place.setLocation(location);
                place.setIcon(placeLine.getString("icon"));
                place.setPlaceId(placeLine.getString("place_id"));

                String detailsHttp = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=AIzaSyDFb37i6VGPj2EG6L7dLO5H7tDhLCqCW2k&placeid=" + place.getPlaceId();
                getPlaceDetails(detailsHttp, place);

                place.setName(placeLine.getString("name"));

                /*JSONArray typesJson = new JSONArray("types");
                String [] types = new String[typesJson.length()];
                for (int a = 0; i < typesJson.length(); i++) {
                    types[a] = typesJson.getString(a);
                }
                place.setTypes(types);*/

                place.setVicinity(placeLine.getString("vicinity"));

                try {
                    place.setRating(placeLine.getInt("rating"));
                } catch (JSONException je) {
                    place.setRating(-1);
                }

                try {
                    JSONArray photosJson = placeLine.getJSONArray("photos");
                    //for (int k = 0; i < photosJson.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject photoLine = (JSONObject) photosJson.get(0);

                        String photoHttp = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&" +
                                "photoreference=" + photoLine.getString("photo_reference") + "&key=AIzaSyDFb37i6VGPj2EG6L7dLO5H7tDhLCqCW2k";

                        place.setPhotoHttp(photoHttp);
                        //place.addPhotoHttp(photoHttp);
                    //}
                } catch (JSONException je) {
                    place.setPhotoHttp(null);
                }
                nearbyPlaces.add(place);
            }

        } catch(MalformedURLException mue){
            System.out.println("A malformed URL exception occurred. " + mue.getMessage());
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("A input/output exception occurred. " + ioe.getMessage());
        } catch(JSONException je){
            System.out.println("A JSON error occurred. " + je.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void getPlaceDetails(String http, Place p) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(http);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            JSONObject resultsJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");
            String address = resultsJson.getString("formatted_address");
            p.setAddress(address);
        } catch(MalformedURLException mue){
            System.out.println("A malformed URL exception occurred. " + mue.getMessage());
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("A input/output exception occurred. " + ioe.getMessage());
        } catch(JSONException je){
            System.out.println("A JSON error occurred. " + je.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        // Thread is finished downloading and parsing JSON, asyncComplete is
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        delegate.asyncComplete(true);
    }
}}
```

The Service to retrieve the device location:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

private LocationListener listener;
private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Intent i = new Intent("location_updates");
            i.putExtra("coordinates", location);
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //noinspection MissingPermission
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, listener);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}}
```

The adapter for the listview:

```
public class PlaceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Place> {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Place> places;

public PlaceAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Place> nearbyPlaces) {
    super(context, R.layout.place_list_item, nearbyPlaces);
    mContext = context;
    this.places = nearbyPlaces;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_list_item, null);

    final Place p = places.get(position);

    TextView placeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_name);
    placeName.setText(p.getName());

    TextView placeAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_address);
    placeAddress.setText(p.getAddress());

    ImageView placeImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_picture);

    if (p.getPhotoHttp() != null) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(p.getPhotoHttp()).into(placeImage);
    } else {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(p.getIcon()).into(placeImage);
    }

    return view;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (broadcastReceiver == null) {
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                mLastLocation = (Location) intent.getExtras().get("coordinates");
                mLat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                mLong = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                nearbyLocations = new GetLocations(NearbyLocationsActivity.this);
                nearbyLocations.execute();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_updates"));
    }
}
```

Move registerReceiver inside if block